# How create session in odata?

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have to use session key in my api. A session key is string value. 
I have to get and return session key.
I create SessionActionFilter which will should add to response session key. 
But I don't understand how change response in filter.

ACtion:

```
[SessionActionFilter]
[Queryable]
public IQueryable<Opportunity> GetOpportunity()
{
    return db.Opportunities;
}
```

Filter:

```
public class SessionActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
        public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            //var sessionKey = "";
            //var oldObjectContent = (actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.Response.Content as ObjectContent);
            //var newContent = new ObjectContent<Opportunity>(result, oldObjectContent.Formatter);
            //actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.Response.Content = newContent;

            base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
        }

}
```

a response data:

```
{   
        "odata.metadata":"http://localhost:2577/odata/$metadata#Opportunity",
        "value":[
                {
                  "Id":4,"Name":"asda"
                },{
                  "Id":7,"Name":"s"
                }   ] 
}
```

I need the response data

```
{   
        "odata.metadata":"http://localhost:2577/odata/$metadata#Opportunity",
        "sessionKey": "VALUE",
        "value":[
                {
                  "Id":4,"Name":"asda"
                },{
                  "Id":7,"Name":"s"
                }   ] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom ODataEntityTypeSerilizer, just follow this sample:             https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v3/CustomODataFormatter/